# How can I get the seed from a Random already created

Tags: .net, vb.net, random

I have to be able to repeat an experiment made with my code, it makes a few random numbers and I need to get the initialization value of my new random() sentence. I have this sentence to make the random object I use

```
Dim r As Random = New Random()
```

As I have read it gets the initialization value from system datetime. If the experiment were successfull I'd needed to be able to repeat it. How could I get the initialization number to be able to do:

```
 Dim r As Random = New Random(OldInitializationValue)
```

I think I'll have to make a Initialization value myself each time I execute my app but If there were a method to save it I'd be glad to know it.

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: You can't. That's the point of "random". You need to explicitly specify the seed in the first call as well,  if you want repeatable sequences

Comment: Apparently the seed value can be explicitly set by a constructor; would it be an option to store the seed value somewhere else to refer to it later?

Comment: PS: any course in R explains that you need to store the seed for repeatability. They also explain that you can't use cryptographing RNGs because they aren't repeatable

Comment: If you want to use the same set of random values for something, you could use a Mersenne Twister.  Whether it is applicable to what you are doing is unclear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Random` does not expose the initial seed, it doesn't even store it so there is no way to retrieve it. So you have to use the [constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctssatww(v=vs.110).aspx) that takes the seed and store it yourself.

```
Dim mySeed As Int32 = Environment.TickCount ' store it somewhere '

Dim myRandom = New Random(mySeed)
For i As Int32 = 1 To 10
    Console.WriteLine(myRandom.Next(1, 100))
Next

' somehwere else
myRandom = New Random(mySeed)
For i As Int32 = 1 To 10
    Console.WriteLine(myRandom.Next(1, 100))
Next
```

Now you can always create a random instance with the same seed to get the same sequence of pseudo random values.

Comment: *Random does not expose the initial seed* Technically the [Microsoft implementation of `Random`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/random.cs,92e3cf6e56571d5a,references) doesn't even "save" the seed anywhere. It uses it immediately and then discards it.

Comment: @xanatos: added it, thanks. The code looks a little bit strange. Why is the seed value overwritten with 1 at the end of the constructor? For security reasons?