# Reproducible random number ( in Java or .NET)?

Tags: java, .net, random, random-seed

Lets have the following sample:

```
import java.util.*; 

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      Random rnd = new Random();
      
      rnd.setSeed(45);
      float v = rnd.nextFloat();
      v = rnd.nextFloat();
      v = rnd.nextFloat();
      v = rnd.nextFloat();
      v = rnd.nextFloat();
      
      float expectedNext = rnd.nextFloat();

      float nextSeend = ???;

      rnd.setSeed(nextSeend);
      v = rnd.nextFloat();

      System.out.println("expected=" + expectedNext + " result=" + v);
    }
}
```

I'm looking for a way to have: ***expectedNext = v***

It means that I'm looking to continue the same sequence (without replaying the 5x nextFloat).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the seed from a Random in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6001368/how-do-i-get-the-seed-from-a-random-in-java)

Comment: For .NET see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36030374/how-can-i-get-the-seed-from-a-random-already-created

Comment: [Another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19512210/how-to-save-the-state-of-a-random-generator-in-c)....

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it does not help. The RND occur on a backend, so I can serialize/save a state etc... (I have no control on the back end, it is ElasticSearch). I need a solution based on pure math by example, like quasi-random + specific seed.